# Can you derive Standard Deviations from a raw mean difference and p-value?

Tags: t-test, p-value, standard-deviation

I have mean averages and a p-value, which I assume was of a t -test. This is the information provided to me:

Treatment N =121    Control N=107
treatment mean = 356.700    treatment control= 357.560
Raw P-value 0.860

Comment: Is the p-value -0.86? A negative value?

Comment: Not negative, Is it possible to get the SDs of treatment and control?  I want to eventually calculate SE

Comment: The answer depends on *which* t-test might have been applied.  Pooled or separate standard deviations? Welch-Satterthwaite approximation or not?  If you only need a rough approximation of the SE, none of these details matter: you can estimate it with simple mental arithmetic.  What do you mean by "raw" p-value?  (It would be a good idea to remove the negative sign from it!)

Comment: Thank you whuber, unfortunately I am looking at a table in a published article and I do not know how they calculated it.

Comment: If you give the reference it may be possible to work out which was used.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that these are two independent groups which seems likely as the numbers are unequal. Let us further assume that the authors did a $t$-test. Then you need to first invert the $p$-value to get the $t$. You do not say what software you use but let us hope it will do that for you. Since $t$ is the mean difference divided by its standard error you now have an extra step which you can do on a calculator.

Of course, if any of my assumptions is unfounded all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

No. You could infer the standard error, which is a function of the standard deviations in each group and the sample sizes. Even with the sample sizes, you could not uniquely determine the individual standard deviations. This is like asking someone to uniquely determine $x$ and $y$ when all you know is that $x+y=2$.